# The detail text label on tableview cell does not refresh with countdown timer

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer, countdown

I have a tableview with basic cellforrow function. I have constructed a timer function as well for my todo list app.

I am trying to create an app that has a running countdown timer in each cell of a tableview, using standard subtitle cells. The timer name is displayed in the textfield and the running timer is displayed in the subtitle.

The idea here is to calculate the remaining time for a task, when a user sets a specific deadline date for the chosen task.

I managed to implement this feature succesfully but the problem I have is when I set the detailtextlabel of a cell (subtitle) to the remaining time left (which displays remaining days/hours/mins/secs ) it does not refresh.

To summarise i want to create a countdown timer feature of a task to show it counting down every second. I want it to load on viewdidload.

is my timer correct? or in the wrong place. I thought it would make sense to have the timer refresh the whole table then if it was inn cellforRow function.

I have tried a timer in the cellforrow function, with no joy. I then made a separate function for the timer to refresh the tableview with reloadData() inside it. This function is called in viewDidLoad. the countdown and everything works, but my label just doesn't update unless I click a cell or add a new todo task.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func startTimer() {
        self.countDownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadTableForTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}



@objc func reloadTableForTimer() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
}






override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    if item.done == true {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Complete!"
            }else {

                var deadlineDatesAll = item.deadlineDate

                if deadlineDatesAll == "" {
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "NO DEADLINE SET"
                } else {
                    // insert code for data disection and then to timer to display each countdown:
                    retrieveDateComponants(deadlineDateChosen: deadlineDatesAll.description)
                    var dataComponants:Array = retrieveDateComponants(deadlineDateChosen: deadlineDatesAll.description)

                    var returnedDueDateString = updateTime(yearExtract: dataComponants[0], monthExtract: dataComponants[1], dayExtract: dataComponants[2], hourExtract: dataComponants[3], minExtract: dataComponants[4], secsExtract: dataComponants[5])
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Due In: \(returnedDueDateString)"
                }

            }
        cell.accessoryType = item.done == true ? .checkmark : .none
    }else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No Item Found"
    }
    return cell
}


//UPDATE countdowns function:
@objc func updateTime(yearExtract:String, monthExtract:String, dayExtract:String,hourExtract:String,minExtract:String, secsExtract:String) -> (String) {

        var deadlineTimeDueString : String = ""

        let futureDate: Date = {
            var future = DateComponents(
                year: Int(yearExtract),
                month: Int(monthExtract),
                day: Int(dayExtract),
                hour: Int(hourExtract),
                minute: Int(minExtract),
                second: Int(secsExtract)            )
            return Calendar.current.date(from: future)!
        }()

        var countdownComp: DateComponents {
            return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: futureDate)
        }

        let countdown = countdownComp //only compute once per call
        let days = countdown.day!
        let hours = countdown.hour!
        let minutes = countdown.minute!
        let seconds = countdown.second!

        print((String(format: "OUTPUT TEST: %02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds)))

        if seconds < 0 {
            deadlineTimeDueString = String("OVERDUE")
        } else if seconds > 0 {
            deadlineTimeDueString = String(format: "%02d Days, %02d Hours, %02d Mins & %02d Secs", days, hours, minutes, seconds)
        }
        return deadlineTimeDueString
    }
```

Everything functions well, except countdown time doesn't refresh label unless I manually click another cell or same one. Remaining time works and updates every second.

any help would be appreciated
Thanks MFK

Comment: Hi Rob Thanks for your reply - I am using deadlineTimeDueString as global variable. it is processed in the function updateTime(). The value I get appears to be spot on for all the cells generated with their times all set. I just want the subtitle to refresh every second, hence showing the countdown in motion visually. - when you say add a log, I'm not sure I understand? like adding a print statement to console?

Comment: I see. thanks for that. I'm still fairly new with Swift, but I appreciate the advice Rob. Do you think having one timer for the table to reload is the right way to go about it?

Comment: I agree the seconds can be a bit too much for UX, definitely will consider that for my update. I'm going to do some test then check from there. will keep you posted. Thanks once again for your help

Comment: Hi Rob - I've managed to create some returns and happy with what I am getting back from the functions. I have edited my code and also inserted the update function in there too. -- you mentioned in your earlier comments that you can update labels of a cell.  how can I go about this? Kind Regards MFK

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest letting the cells update their own labels, but so that they update all at the same time, have the controller post notification when cells should be update.

So, you can create a notification for your timer:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let timerFired = Notification.Name(rawValue: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".timer")
}
```

The view controller would then post this notification:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var todos = ...

    private weak var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .timerFired, object: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The `UITableViewDataSource` could then pass the “to do” to the cell:

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return todos.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCell", for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell
        cell.configure(for: todos[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

The cell can then tie this all together, observing the notification and updating the text appropriately:

```
class ToDoCell: UITableViewCell {
    private var todo: ToDo?
    private var token: NSObjectProtocol?

    private static let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
        return formatter
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addObservers()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addObservers()
    }

    deinit {
        removeObservers()
    }

    func configure(for todo: ToDo) {
        self.todo = todo
        textLabel?.text = todo.name
        if todo.done {
            removeObservers()
            detailTextLabel?.textColor = .black
            detailTextLabel?.text = "Done!"
            accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            addObservers()
            updateTime()
            accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
}

private extension ToDoCell {
    func addObservers() {
        guard token == nil else { return }

        token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .timerFired, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.updateTime()
        }
    }

    func removeObservers() {
        if let token = token {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
        }
    }

    func updateTime() {
        guard let date = todo?.deadline else {
            detailTextLabel?.text = "No deadline specified"
            detailTextLabel?.textColor = .black
            return
        }

        let now = Date()
        if date < now {
            detailTextLabel?.text = "Past due " + (ToDoCell.formatter.string(from: date, to: now) ?? "")
            detailTextLabel?.textColor = .red
        } else {
            detailTextLabel?.text = ToDoCell.formatter.string(from: now, to: date)
            detailTextLabel?.textColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I’m using `DateComponentsFormatter` with `maximumUnitCount` of `2`, so that I don’t see annoying level of detail. So rather than “7 days, 12 hours, 42 minutes, 8 seconds”, I’ll just see “7 days, 12 hours”, but it will show it where the seconds might be relevant (e.g. less than 1 hour away):

[image]

But the details are less important than the general design principle of pulling a lot of the cell-specific code into the `UITableViewCell` subclass rather than putting it in the view controller.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! Appreciate it Rob. You're a star!